# Как правильно описать метод, возвращающий указатель на структуру

Tags: c++

Файл terminal.h

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    class CTerminal
    {
    private:
        struct SCard
        {
            int id;
            int cardnumb;
            string cardhold;
            int pin;
            int balance;
        };
    public:
        SCard * regcard(int _cardnumb, string _cardhold, int _pin);
    };
```

---

Файл terminal.cpp

```
#include "term.h"

SCard * CTerminal::regcard()
```

Проблема возникает с правильным описанием последней строки. КРасным подчеркивается SCard (идентификатор SCard не определен)

Comment: Прототипы функции в объявлении и определении должны совпадать, то есть в определении функции вы обязаны указать тот же самый список параметров.

Comment: Все равно подчеркивается красным

Comment: Смотрите мой ответ.

Comment: Определите структуру в  секции public:. Название вашей структуры которое используется вне класса (или методов класса) где она описана, это CTerminal::SCard, а не просто SCard. P.S. string лучше передавать по ссылке или константной ссылке.

Answer (score 2):

Если я вас правильно понял, то определение функции может выглядеть следующим образом

```
CTerminal::SCard * CTerminal::regcard( int _cardnumb, string _cardhold, int _pin ) 
{ 
    /*...*/ 
}
```

Например,

```
CTerminal::SCard * CTerminal::regcard( int _cardnumb, string _cardhold, int _pin ) 
{ 
    return new  SCard { SOME_ID, _cardnumb, _cardhold, _pin, SOME_BALANCE };
}
```

Так как у вас сама структура объявлена с классом доступа private, то вызывать метод вы можете следующим образом

```
auto p = CTerminalObject.regcard( /* arguments */ );
```

Хотя конечно лучше было бы объявить структуру с классом доступа `public` если указатель на нее вы хотите использовать вне класса.